# Getting the initial state after unchecked checkbox input with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am building a filter section where I am fetching data through my API and setting up a new state ‘[result]’. The process is simple since data are fetched on click event and with certain condition. Data are stocked in an array since the user is able to filter several input checked.

My goal is to remove a particular index when I unchecked a checkbox input and if array is empty then reset my state to the data it fetched when the page first loaded.

I heard lodash could help me building my feature though I don't know how to implement on my react-app.

How could I build this process ?

Here’s my code :

```
handleFilterButtons = event => {
var filterIcons = event.target.getAttribute("name");
var valueInput = event.target.value;
var apiFilters = `https://backend.greatsaigon.com/api/v1/en/directories/${
  this.state.directory
}/venues`;
axios
  .get(apiFilters)
  .then(response => {
    let result;
    let prevResult = [];
    let toggleButton;

    response.data.forEach(req => {
      if (filterIcons === "Hair") {
        if (req.options.beauty.hair.treatment !== "0") {
          req.options.beauty.hair.treatment.forEach(res => {
            if (res === valueInput && toggleButton !== undefined) {
              result = req;
              this.state.stockResult.unshift(result);
            }
          });
        }
      } else if (filterIcons === "Nails") {
        if (req.options.beauty.nails.treatment !== "0") {
          req.options.beauty.nails.treatment.forEach(res => {
            if (res === valueInput) {
              result = req;
              this.state.stockResult.unshift(result);
            }
          });
        }
      } else if (filterIcons === "Spa & Massage") {
        if (req.options.beauty.spa.treatment !== "0") {
          req.options.beauty.spa.treatment.forEach(res => {
            if (res === valueInput) {
              result = req;
              this.state.stockResult.unshift(result);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      result: _.uniq(this.state.stockResult),
      isToggle: toggleButton
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

};

Comment: Theres a lot of missing data here to give a good answer... also i dont know what scares me more, the fact that you have written out this method for each kind of filter, or the fact that you are directly mutating state, or that this doesn't look to be in a react class, or that if it is you are executing request methods in a view with callbacks and no mount handling

Comment: Datas will be fetch according to the name of my category and only if the string that I set up in my value input isn’t empty.

Then I update my state ‘stockResult’ and correct datas are fetched and displayed.

Category > String Input Value !== ‘ ’ > Add Items in array > setState : stockResult = result > Datas are displayed

Since we have sevarals categories and we wanna be able to ‘multi filter’ then that’s the only way I found out working for me.

Though I believe there’s a better way.

What kind of information do you need more ?